# how to remove duplicates in a huge python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a huge python list, about 100 MB size with strings and integers. I have some strings as triplicates and duplicates. I have tried to remove duplicates with this code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

duplicates = [.......large size list of 100 MB....]

remove = OrderedDict.fromkeys(duplicates).keys()

print remove
```

I have done with small size lists and it works good, with this large list, it has taken me a whole day and am not yet done. Any suggestions on how this can be done in minutes, ..fewer hrs??. I have tried CUDA installation in Ubuntu to work it out but I keep getting errors: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14976114)

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove all of a duplicate or only the *others*. Say I give you `[a,b,a,c,a]`. Do you want `[a,b,c]` or `[b,c]`?

Comment: This sounds like a someone strange operation to want to do on a list. Are you sure you want to use a `list`? If you use a different data structure (such as a set), this kind of operation would be trivial.

Comment: @willem, if i have ['a','b','a','c',], i want [ 'a','b','c',]

Comment: @kevin, i tried a set with the same prolonged duration

Comment: Why did you use a list in the first place? Is the order important? Instead of removing duplicates from a list, could you consider not adding the duplicates in the first place? Where do the data come from? Could you provide more information on what you're actually doing?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order? If not, just use `remove = set(duplicates)` If order is important, as Raymond Hettinger says, there is no faster way than what you're doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order/39835527#39835527

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is efficient enough, but one simple way to solve it is to cast your list into a set.

```
def unique(objects):
    return list(sorted(set(objects)))
```

Comment: still slow in processing the data